# Excluir três versões de imagens com nomes e tamanhos diferentes

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, imagem, entrada-de-dados, diretório

Tenho um código que seleciona 1 imagem e apaga. Executa muito bem, tanto a exclusão do arquivo, quanto a remoção do registro no BD, mas estou implantando três versões da mesma imagem para diminuir a reinderização... O codigo (backend) que eu uso para fazer upload das imagens, só apresenta a de tamanho 600x600px, mas no BD eu tenho mais duas versões 300x300px e 800x800px. eu consegui criar o codigo para excluir as três versões do BD, mas na pasta eu não tenho idéia de como vercer a dificuldade de apagar as 3 e só consigo apagar a que é apresentada e selecionada (600x600). Alguém pode me ajudar com qq idéia?

```
            if (isset($_POST["acao"])) {
                $acao = $_POST["acao"];
                if ($acao == "excluirselecionadas") {
                    $pasta = $_POST['pastaselecao'];
                    $id_anuncio = $_POST["id_anuncioelecao"];

                    $seleciona_alt = $login->prepare("SELECT * FROM anuncio WHERE id = ?");
                    $seleciona_alt->execute([$id_anuncio]);
                    $conteudo_alt = $seleciona_alt->fetch();

                    if (!isset($_POST['check'])) {
                        erro("Selecione uma imagem!");
                    } else {
                        $check = $_POST['check'];
                        foreach ($check as $registro) {
                            // Seleciona todas as versões da imagem
                            $sel_fotos = $login->prepare("SELECT * FROM anuncio_fotos WHERE id = ? AND anuncio_id = ?");
                            $sel_fotos->execute([$registro, $id_anuncio]);
                            $fotos = $sel_fotos->fetchAll();

                            foreach ($fotos as $foto) {
                                // Adiciona mensagem de debug
                                echo "Excluindo imagem com ID {$foto['id']}<br>";

                                // Exclui as outras versões da imagem (300x300px e 800x800px)
                                $excluir_300x300 = $login->prepare("DELETE FROM anuncio_fotos WHERE indice = ? AND tamanho = 300 AND anuncio_id = ?");
                                $excluir_800x800 = $login->prepare("DELETE FROM anuncio_fotos WHERE indice = ? AND tamanho = 800 AND anuncio_id = ?");

                                $excluir_300x300->execute([$foto['indice'], $id_anuncio]);
                                $excluir_800x800->execute([$foto['indice'], $id_anuncio]);

                                // Exclui a entrada no banco de dados
                                $excluir = $login->prepare("DELETE FROM anuncio_fotos WHERE id = ?");
                                $result = $excluir->execute([$foto['id']]);

                                // Adiciona mensagem de debug
                                if ($result) {
                                    echo "Entrada no banco de dados excluída com sucesso<br>";
                                } else {
                                    echo "Erro ao excluir entrada no banco de dados<br>";
                                }

                                // Exclui o arquivo físico
                                $caminho = caminho("anuncios/$pasta/{$foto['foto']}");
                                echo "Excluindo arquivo físico em $caminho<br>";
                                $result = unlink($caminho);

                                // Adiciona mensagem de debug
                                if ($result) {
                                    echo "Arquivo físico excluído com sucesso<br>";
                                } else {
                                    echo "Erro ao excluir arquivo físico<br>";
                                }

                                // Exclui as outras versões da imagem (300x300px e 800x800px)
                                $caminho_300x300 = caminho("anuncios/$pasta/{$foto['foto300']}");
                                echo "Excluindo arquivo físico em $caminho_300x300<br>";
                                unlink($caminho_300x300);

                                $caminho_800x800 = caminho("anuncios/$pasta/{$foto['foto800']}");
                                echo "Excluindo arquivo físico em $caminho_800x800<br>";
                                unlink($caminho_800x800);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ok("Suas imagens foram deletadas com sucesso!");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -3):

acabei de encontrar a solução. Vou postar aqui:

```
            if (isset($_POST["acao"])) {
                $acao = $_POST["acao"];
                if ($acao == "excluirselecionadas") {
                    $pasta = $_POST['pastaselecao'];
                    $id_anuncio = $_POST["id_anuncioelecao"];

                    $seleciona_alt = $login->prepare("SELECT * FROM anuncio WHERE id = ?");
                    $seleciona_alt->execute([$id_anuncio]);
                    $conteudo_alt = $seleciona_alt->fetch();

                    if (!isset($_POST['check'])) {
                        erro("Selecione uma imagem!");
                    } else {
                        $check = $_POST['check'];
                        foreach ($check as $registro) {
                            // Busca o registro da imagem
                            $sel_fotos = $login->prepare("SELECT * FROM anuncio_fotos WHERE id = ? AND anuncio_id = ?");
                            $sel_fotos->execute([$registro, $id_anuncio]);
                            $fotos = $sel_fotos->fetch(); // Considerando que você só precisa de um registro

                            if ($fotos) {
                                // Adiciona mensagem de debug
                                echo "Excluindo imagem com ID {$fotos['id']}<br>";

                                // Exclui a entrada no banco de dados
                                $excluir = $login->prepare("DELETE FROM anuncio_fotos WHERE id = ?");
                                $result = $excluir->execute([$fotos['id']]);

                                // Adiciona mensagem de debug
                                if ($result) {
                                    echo "Entrada no banco de dados excluída com sucesso<br>";
                                } else {
                                    echo "Erro ao excluir entrada no banco de dados<br>";
                                }

                                // Exclui o arquivo físico
                                $caminho = caminho("anuncios/$pasta/{$fotos['foto']}");
                                echo "Excluindo arquivo físico em $caminho<br>";
                                $result = unlink($caminho);

                                // Adiciona mensagem de debug
                                if ($result) {
                                    echo "Arquivo físico excluído com sucesso<br>";
                                } else {
                                    echo "Erro ao excluir arquivo físico<br>";
                                }

                                // Busca outras duas imagens com o mesmo "anuncio_id" e o mesmo "indice"
                                $sel_outras_fotos = $login->prepare("SELECT * FROM anuncio_fotos WHERE anuncio_id = ? AND indice = ? AND id != ? LIMIT 2");
                                $sel_outras_fotos->execute([$id_anuncio, $fotos['indice'], $registro]);
                                $outras_fotos = $sel_outras_fotos->fetchAll();

                                foreach ($outras_fotos as $outra_foto) {
                                    // Adiciona mensagem de debug
                                    echo "Excluindo imagem com ID {$outra_foto['id']}<br>";

                                    // Exclui a entrada no banco de dados
                                    $excluir_outra = $login->prepare("DELETE FROM anuncio_fotos WHERE id = ?");
                                    $result_outra = $excluir_outra->execute([$outra_foto['id']]);

                                    // Adiciona mensagem de debug
                                    if ($result_outra) {
                                        echo "Entrada no banco de dados excluída com sucesso<br>";
                                    } else {
                                        echo "Erro ao excluir entrada no banco de dados<br>";
                                    }

                                    // Exclui o arquivo físico
                                    $caminho_outra = caminho("anuncios/$pasta/{$outra_foto['foto']}");
                                    echo "Excluindo arquivo físico em $caminho_outra<br>";
                                    $result_outra = unlink($caminho_outra);

                                    // Adiciona mensagem de debug
                                    if ($result_outra) {
                                        echo "Arquivo físico excluído com sucesso<br>";
                                    } else {
                                        echo "Erro ao excluir arquivo físico<br>";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ok("Suas imagens foram deletadas com sucesso!");
                }
            }
```